# Collection left to right cell not showing correctly

Tags: swift, xcode

Collection view cells are not showing correctly from left to right. It has the gap in center. How can I correct this issue.
[image]

```
collectionView_.register(UINib.init(nibName: String(describing: GoalSelectionCollectionViewCell.self), bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
collectionView_.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    
if let flowLayout = collectionView_?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let itemSize:CGSize = CGSize(width: 80.0, height: 30.0);

    return itemSize;
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 20.0;
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 20.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and you also need to set `minimumLineSpacing` (min spacing between lines) and `minimumInteritemSpacing` (min spacing in between items in same row)

Comment: I have also set both methods. But it's still the same. I have edited the answer with more code

Comment: Are you creating this collectionview programmatically or through UI. If programatically, you'll have to create a custom Flowlayout and assign it to your collection view for this to work

Comment: I created it through the XIB interface. The XIB has a UICollectionViewFlowLayout inside UICollectionView. I also added insetForSectionAt UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0). Still the same the cell are not aligned left side.

Comment: Try removing the constraints within the cell, maybe those are messing with the layout of the cells